# updating the ruby gem 1.8.5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu, rubygems

hiii 
 i am trying to update my gem file. Current version of gem is 1.8.5 
When i am trying to update it using command " gem install rubygems-update -v 1.8.5 " it is giving following error
**

> ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError)
>       SocketError: getaddrinfo: Name or service not known
>   (http://rubygems.org/gems/rubygems-update-1.8.5.gem)

**

I am working on ubuntu 10.04

also i tried to update using command " gem update --system "
it is giving the error as below
Updating rubygems-update
**

> ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::GemNotFoundException)
>       Could not find a valid gem 'rubygems-update' (1.8.6) locally or in
>   a repository

**
i also tried the solution given on the link http://lightyearsoftware.com/2009/07/updating-rubygems-to-recent-1-3-x/

please help me to resolve the problem..

Comment: do you get any error if you execute: gem list -r

Comment: hi Massomolliano. I do not get any errors when I run that..

Comment: @madyrockss Have you tried to download the gem from rubygems.org and install it locally on your machine? Does ruby give you another error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are under Windows 7, run the command prompt as Administrator.

Read this [thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/bangalorerug/fDvOfLNZ0pQ). The error reported is the same of yours.

Try to apply the [Google DNS](http://code.google.com/speed/public-dns/) configuration to your connection.

Otherwise you can try to install locally the gem, downloading it on [rubygems.org](http://www.rubygems.org). After this, in the directory you downloaded the gem, try to install it locally with the command: `gem install gem_name --local`

Comment: Thanks AlbertS when i used google DNs [8.8.8.8] it worked for me.... Thanks a lot...

Answer (score 1):

I also had this error.  I resolved it with

```
gem uninstall rubygems-update
```

(you may need to be sudo) and then reinstalled with

```
gem install rubygems-update
```

now it's working fine, hope this is helpful

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

- Manually uninstall the gem you want to remove: gem uninstall [gemToUinistall]
- Download the gem manually from http://rubygems.org/
- try to install the gem from local : gem install [gemToInstall]