# ruby gem update and gem update --system error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

On my Linux system Ubuntu 14.04.2, When I run gem update, I got this:

```
Updating installed gems
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError)
Errno::ECONNREFUSED: Connection refused - connect(2) for "s3.amazonaws.com" port 443 (https://api.rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz)
```

And When I run gem update --system, I got this:

```
Updating rubygems-update
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::SpecificGemNotFoundException)
Could not find a valid gem 'rubygems-update' (= 2.4.8) locally or in a repository
```

How do I resolve this problem?

Comment: Please look at these existing answers:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6841473/updating-the-ruby-gem-1-8-5

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9962051/could-not-find-a-valid-gem-in-any-repository-rubygame-and-others

Comment: thx, I have already solve this problem.